# How to get started with blender

Tags: animation, video

I am new to blender , I need to make a 2 min vid. Can anyone help me get started ?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). If you don't know where to start, check [BlenderGuru's YT Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/AndrewPPrice). If you want more specific answers, ask more specific questions. Good luck.

Comment: This playlist is also very useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF1qEhBSfq4&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6 - But phew, 2 minutes is A LOT of work, I hope you can make it :)